# want to add absolute url by wp_enqueue_script() in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi all I want to add absolute url of scripts to wordpress. I'm using `wp_enqueue_script();`

But it always add my own domain to script's url. I'm adding url like

```
//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=SyBjVX7N2HGlLg-ygAEy9VUCzn6zPkU2XM0&libraries=places&language=en
```

in browser I always got like

```
/wp-content/plugins/plugname/assets/js/https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=SyBjVX7N2HGlLg-ygAEy9VUCzn6zPkU2XM0&#038;libraries=places&#038;language=en
```

Don't now how to remove `/wp-content/plugins/plugname/assets/js/`

Comment: Can you provide your code of how you are enqueuing your scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Put this :)

wp_enqueue_script('maps', 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=SyBjVX7N2HGlLg-ygAEy9VUCzn6zPkU2XM0&libraries=places&language=en' , array(), '1.0.0', false);

Comment: Put your enqueue function here? That will help us to solve

Comment: Sorry HarshU Chilz, I can't.

Answer (score 0):

No idea how you have given the url, see below code, I tested below code and it is working well

```
  wp_enqueue_script('google-maps', '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=SyBjVX7N2HGlLg-ygAEy9VUCzn6zPkU2XM0&libraries=places&language=en', array(), '3', true);
```

Comment: wp_enqueue_script() always removing 
//maps.googleapis.com from url

Comment: Can you please post the code you have given, so that I can check it. The above code is working fine in latest wordpress version.

Comment: It's a bit complicated,
I think some other wp plugin conflicts.
Thanks